# How do I automatically show different resources for light vs dark themes in Android?

Tags: android, resources, themes

As I understand, there are two built in themes for Android, Light and Dark. I want my application to display different resources based on which theme the user is using (NOT by having the user explicitly specify a theme in my app!). Is this possible? If so, is it possible to do via xml resources, or is a programmatic approach required?

Note: Yes, I've read http://d.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html at least thrice. It seems like all it tells me how to do is set one specific theme or styles to my element, rather than displaying light/dark elements correctly.

Comment: "based on which theme the user is using": where does the user choose this theme? Doesn't get clear to me. There's no settings for that in  the device settings (i.e. display section).

Comment: Sorry, to be more specific, "Theme" vs "Theme.Light" (as seen in http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/res/res/values/themes.xml;h=6b3d7407d1c895a3c297e60d5beac98e2d34c271;hb=HEAD )

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it can be done via XML resources.

From https://developer.android.com/preview/features/darktheme#themes_and_styles:

> Your themes and styles should avoid hard-coded colors or icons intended for use under a light theme. You should use theme attributes (preferred) or night-qualified resources instead.

So yes, there are resource qualifiers for that, see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#NightQualifier
: `night` and `notnight` suffixes.

I find [Material theme website](https://material.io/develop/android/theming/dark/) to be pretty good at explaining this but the most important part is:

> Alternatively, if you want to define separate `Light` and `Dark` themes for your app, you can inherit from `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light` in the `values` directory, and `Theme.MaterialComponents` in the `values-night` directory. E.g.:
>
> res/values/themes.xml
>
> ```
> <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
>     <!-- ... -->
> </style>
> ```
>
> res/values-night/themes.xml
>
> ```
> <style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents">
>    <!-- ... -->
> </style>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is a site you can check for alternative drawable folders.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Also, this document might be helpful.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

For regular themes: I'm not aware of any functions in Android about that, you might need to develop it yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen those pages several times. I'm trying to inherit from Theme.Light vs Theme without having to have my application specifically pick a theme to use.

Comment: Something like this: `<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light">
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    </style>`